# CSS flex space-between issue

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a unique problem where I want the link elements inside a div to use flex space-between BUT these links open up modal layers and the modal div is actually within the parent div. Now just having this empty div in the #parent div is causing additional spacing. How can I resolve this? By the way ... I cannot reorganize the markup ... the modal divs have to be within the parent div.

So something like this:

```css
#parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#parent a {
  max-width: 46px;
  margin: 0 1%;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <a href="#" id="modal1link">LINK 1</a>
  <a href="#" id="modal2link">LINK 2</a>
  <a href="#" id="modal3link">LINK 3</a>
  <div id="modal1" class="modal"></div>
  <div id="modal2" class="modal"></div>
  <div id="modal3" class="modal"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're going to have to reorganise the markup, if only because you can't have multiple elements with the same ID...

Comment: All the id's seem to be unique.

Comment: @conordarcy You sure?

Comment: @conordarcy link e div it has the same id ;)

Comment: Oh yes, see it now haha.

Comment: Sorry ignore that ... this was just an example. Let me edit the original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume the modals will be full screen & hidden by default? If so:

```
.modal {
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
  }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Although I used position: absolute. I just needed to take it out of the inline flow of elements.